# Why is this not evaluating properly? (Project Euler 9 - C)

Tags: c

The following is my answer to [Project Euler #9](https://projecteuler.net/problem=9), which seems logically correct but won't evaluate properly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int a=0,b=0,c=0,a1=0,b1=0,c1=0,product=0;
    bool cond = false;
    for (a=1;cond==false && a<334;a++){
        for (b=a;(a+b)<500;b++){
            c = 1000-a-b;
            if (a*a + b*b == c*c){
                cond = true;
                product = a*b*c;
                a1 = a;
                b1 = b;
                c1 = c;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Triple has constituents (%d, %d, %d) with product %d.",a1,b1,c1,product);
    return 0;
}
```

I checked this with other C-family solutions to the problem and it was exactly the same approach in terms of logic, yet it always outputs (0,0,0) rather than the real triple. Why is this? I think it has something to do with the if statement, but I'm not certain nor can I identify anything wrong with it.

(I am well aware there might be something simple I'm overlooking, and if so I'll delete the question after I get an answer.)

Comment: maybe there's a bug...

Comment: You only have 2 loops, one for `a` and the other for `b`. `c` is determined from `c=1000-a-b`. Of course you will never hit a solution like `a=3, b=4, c=5` because they don't add up to 1000. What solution were you expecting?

Comment: @Matt From the Euler site `There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which a + b + c = 1000.`

Comment: Ok I didn't read that part :) The limit of 500 is too low. Increase that and you'll have your answer.

Comment: @Matt It was only the 4th line?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: @PeterM I'm referring to the line `for (b=a;(a+b)<500;b++){` yes.

Comment: @Matt You can raise the limit, i.e. `(a+b)<1000` or just replace it with `b<500`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @remyabel Both seem to work fine.

Comment: @Matt Okay, because I was confused as to why you were suggesting that instead of the other way until I tested it myself.

Comment: It was fixed as noted below. I thought the statement evaluated the same as the b < s/2 I saw in other solutions, clearly an indication I spent too much time staring that this. Thank you for the help.

Comment: To use `bool` type literals, you should include `stdbool.h` header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the limit check of your second for loop that is limiting your solution range.

Thats all I'll say

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, the only thing you need to fix is this line:

```
for (b=a;b<500;b++){
```

---

Here is a solution.

> a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> = (s - a - b)<sup>2</sup>
>
> From the condition `a < b < c`, we conclude that
>   `a <= (s - 3) / 3` and `b < (s - a) / 2`.

Note that `s = 1000`, but we're using magic numbers here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
    int a,b,c; 
    for (a=1;a<333;a++) {
        for (b=a+1;b<500;b++) 
        { 
            c=1000-a-b; 
            if (c>b) { 
                if (a*a+b*b==c*c) 
                    printf("a=%d b=%d c=%d a*b*c=%d\n",a,b,c,a*b*c); 
            } 
        } 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: +1 for first valid answer

Comment: Thanks, I made that exact fix after I saw Peter's answer.

Comment: could you please explain how did you find the upper bound of `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 1):

Your limit on `a + b` is too low. For example, the triple (200, 399, 401) will never get checked, since `c` will always be at least 500. A better (and correct) limit for the sum is `1000 - 333`.

Comment: Thanks, first sentence was all I needed.